# Provision multiple environment of infrastructure reusing Terraform code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-template-file

Im new to Terraform and I have this doubt. I've created a set of multiple resources for GCP (instances, vpc, subnet, secret manager, etc), so far so good, but the requirement is to re-use the same code for multiple future deployments (not environments). That means, this week I'll deploy the whole set for an specific region with specific names, next week I might need to deploy the same set for another region with different names and two weeks later another (but the previous ones won't be deleted), the resources will always remain the same and will be used for PROD activities.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Normally one would collect these resources into a module, and then declare the module once per region with a provider configuration specifying each region input to the module: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/configuration#selecting-alternate-provider-configurations. Note the second example with the module declaration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by using workspaces, simple creating a new workspace for each deployment with terraform workspace new  and deploying from that workspace in particular. If another set of infra needed to be deploy, I create a new one, change and re-deploy again, using the same code for all deploys.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have Terraform code looks like example below and want to reuse that code across environments:

```
├── modules
│   ├── module1
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── module2
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
```

`module1` and `module1` contains your reusable code. 
Create per environment directories so you directory looks like that:

```
├── environments
│   └── env1
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ...
├── modules
│   ├── module1
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── module2
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
```

Inside each environment you need to include reusable modules into `env1/main.tf` file:

```
module "module1-env1" {
  source = "../../modules/module1"
  vpc    = var.vpc                 <- list all you variables like that
  subnet = var.subnet
  ...
}
module "module2-env1" {
  source = "../../modules/module2"
  vpc    = var.vpc                 <- list all you variables like that
  subnet = var.subnet
  ...
}
```

All variables should be defined in `env1/variables.tf` and values provided in `env1/terraform.tfvars`. 
All other environments should be configured in a similar way.

Congratulation! Now you can provision multiple infrastructure using the same code.